# Adding an Index over a table or over a view in SQL

Tags: sql, indexing, database-design, view

I have a table with around half million records that is updated/inserted on daily basis.
I need to add some indexes to make my queries faster.Is it recommended to add them over the table itself or over a view on that table?
All my queries are over the view when fetching data and displaying it on website.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and tuning recommendations are highly vendor specific (not every DBMS will let you create an index on a view). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are creating indexed views performance will be impacted due to regular insert/update operations on base table as index needs to be updated as well so it's a tradeoff which needs to be measured that how much performance gain you see after creating indexed view and how much performance degrades on insert/update operation on base table.

I quote SQL server official documentaion below

***"When executing DML on a table referenced by a large number of indexed views, or fewer but very complex indexed views, those referenced indexed views will have to be updated as well. As a result, DML query performance can degrade significantly, or in some cases, a query plan cannot even be produced. In such scenarios, test your DML queries before production use, analyze the query plan and tune/simplify the DML statement."***